# detecting dependencies on delete

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to delete rows from a table where no foreign key dependencies exist. If they do exist the rows should be marked as "deadfiled" to maintain relational integrity. The goal is to keep only necessary data.

The delete would affect only the one row; it does not trigger a cascading delete nor am I trying to delete the dependents. For example, a customer row is referenced in many other tables such as invoice, agreement, change order, and so on, that customer row should be marked as "deadfiled". If there are no such references, then the customer row can be deleted from the table.

I am looking for advice about the best way to handle this from the client application code. I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.

Here is the current approach, which relies on Postgres' "knowledge" of foreign key dependencies:

```
Begin transation
delete row x
if SQLSTATE Error Code = 23503
  update row set deadfiled = true
if success
  commit transaction
else rollback
```

In some posts it appears the above method is considered fragile. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not just set `deadfiled` always and don't bother whether or not there are dependencies?  You will have to filter for `deadfiled` anyway to separate the live from the zombie rows.  I doubt that physically deleting some rows will give you any measurable performance boost.

Comment: or do that and have some "cleanup" task that removes dead rows that aren't referenced. You could even call it "autovacuum" ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've never really used PostgreSQL but it kind of looks like your using a *cursor-based* approach.

How about a *set-based* solution instead?

Run an update query that checks for the existence of dependencies and flags those records...

```
update parent 
set deadfiled = true
where
    exists (
        select *
        from dependency1 as d1
        where d1.id = parent.id
    )
    or
    exists (
        select *
        from depenedency2 as d2
        where d2.id = parent.id
    )
    --or ... etc.,  keep adding dependency checks
```

... and then deletes those where the flag is not set:

```
delete from parent where deadfiled = false
```

Comment: Your suggestion works, of course, but requires a lot of coding if the relationships touch many tables.

Comment: Upon reading your question, I realize that you thought I was deleting the dependencies. That isn't what is intended.

Comment: @Mophilly no, i see that you want to delete that which is depended on, not the dependents. You raise a good point in regards to the effort it would take when there are a lot of dependencies.

Comment: I'm searching for the existence of the `SET QUIT COMPLAINING ABOUT FAILED DELETES AND FINISH SUCCESSFUL DELETES = ON` option, that would be a handy feature

Comment: @J Cooper FYI, MySQL has `DELETE IGNORE` which does just that, it deletes everything it can and just ignores rows that it can't delete because of foreign key constraints. Unfortunately PostgreSQL doesn't have that, so that's not really the answer to this question though..

Comment: @Mophilly: The SET base approach is clearly superior (in elegance and in execution time). However, this can be much simper, yet: `DELETE FROM parent WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ...) AND NOT EXISTS (...)`. If you are not sure which foreign keys point to your table, you could use [pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/), select the table and see all depending objects in the top right window.